# Eliminate CSS from being applied to child list items

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML structure building out my menu:

```
<div id=”navigation”>
<ul>
    <li class=”level1”>Top Level Menu item
        <div class=”sublevel”>    
            <ul>
                <li class=”level2”>Second Level Item1
                    <ul>
                        <li class=”level3”>Third Level Item1</li>
                        <li class=”level3”>Third Level Item2</li>
                        <li class=”level3”>Third Level Item3</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
<li class=”level2”>Second Level Item2
                    <ul>
                        <li class=”level3”>Third Level Item4</li>
                        <li class=”level3”>Third Level Item5</li>
                        <li class=”level3”>Third Level Item6</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

In CSS I am applying a style to the `level 2` class like so:

```
#navigation .level1 ul li {
background: #acacac;
padding-bottom: 40px !important;
border-radius: 10px;
position: absolute;
}
```

The problem is that this is applied to all the child menu items as well.  How can I specify to only apply this to the `level2` items and not the `level3`?

I have attempted a variety of `>` and `+` flags per CSS docs, but no luck.

Comment: why doesn't `#navigation .level1 ul li.level2` fit your conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the selector to use the direct child operator:

```
#navigation .level1 .sublevel > ul > li {
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple, just use the `:not()` rule

```
#navigation .level1 ul li:not(.level3) {
  background: #acacac;
  padding-bottom: 40px !important;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**[More on `:not()` from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot)**

> The negation CSS pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation
>   taking a simple selector X as an argument. It matches an element that
>   is not represented by the argument. X must not contain another
>   negation selector, or any pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#navigation .level1 .level2 li {
background: #acacac;
padding-bottom: 40px !important;
border-radius: 10px;
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: you forgot a `.`, bro, and this doesn't work.  it will select the `.level3` `li`s and completely exclude the `.level2` ones.